# alertmanager filter by tag (timescale backend)

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager, timescaledb

I am using [alertmanager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/) configured to read from a [timescale](https://www.timescale.com/) db shared with other Prometheus/alertmanager systems.

I would like to set/check alerts only for services including a specific tag, therefore wondering how could I configure prometheus to apply only for specific tags?

This is what currently I am using:

```yaml
# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9093']

remote_write:
  - url: https://promscale.host:9201/write

remote_read:
  - url: https://promscale.host:9201/read
    read_recent: true
...
```

I found there is an option `alert_relabel_configs` but is unclear for me the usage of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

FYI, `alert_relabel_configs` are used for alert relabeling to alerts before they are sent to the Alertmanager

To use `alert_relabel_configs` below is the example to add a new tag on matching the relabel config set:

```
   alert_relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [ log_level ]
      regex: warn
      target_label: severity
      replacement: warn
```

**Note**: The alerts are only changed when sent to alertmanager. They are
not changed in the Prometheus UI.

To test the relabel config online you can use https://relabeler.promlabs.com/

If you are using Prometheus Operator configuring alert relabeling rules should be done in `additionalAlertRelabelConfigs` of `PrometheusSpec`, more details: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/1805